List of mathematicians or physicists once a high school teacher
In my impression, many famous mathematicians were once a high school teacher. I can name Weierstrass, Sylow, Lebesgue.
Can anyone name more?

I am not sure the construction of such lists serves the purposes of this site well. What qualifies a person as a"famous mathematician"? Where have you looked for people meeting your criteria? You will likely find numerous examples, as teachers with a Ph.D. were quite common at German Gynasiums prior to WW2. Having said that, Kummer would be another example: he taught math and physics at a high school for ten or eleven years prior to becoming a professor at the University of Breslau. Yet another example would be Wilhelm Ackermann

Edwin Hubble worked as high school teacher before getting his PhD does that count?

Hermann Grassmann never managed to secure a professorship, hence stayed a high school teacher all his life. As side projects to his teaching he produced exterior algebra and many aspects of multilinear algebra, an important contribution to color perception and the still used translation of the Rigveda from Sanskrit into German.

Many German mathematicians of 19 century started their careers as high school (gymnasium) teachers. Besides
those already named in the comments, I can name  Wilhelm Killing and
Hermann Schubert, but in fact this was a typical career. Some taught in high school for all their life.
Of the French 20 century mathematicians I mention Paul Montel. I don't think it makes sense to make a list since it will be too large.
Remark. One also should not forget Johann Balmer, who was not a professional physicist/mathematician, but a high school teacher, and who made one of the most important discoveries: by playing with numbers, he found a simple pattern in the spectral lines of hydrogen, which triggered the development eventually leading to discovery of quantum mechanics.

Giuseppe Vitali
From "Giuseppe Vitali: Real and Complex Analysis and Differential Geometry" by Maria Teresa Borgato in "Mathematicians in Bologna 1861-1960" edited by Salvatore Coen:

In 1902, Vitali left university since he had accepted a position as a mathematics teacher in a secondary school (better paid than the post of assistant at university), first in Sassari and then in Voghera (until 1904) and finally in the “C. Colombo” Secondary School of Genoa. At that time it was not unusual for a person to begin a university career with a period of secondary school teaching (other examples are Luigi Cremona and Cesare Arzelà), but it was a great pity that it took the university up till 1922 to concede full research activity to such talent like that of Vitali.


Let me quote a well-known passage from Giovanni Sansone’ repertoire on
famous mathematicians graduated from the Scuola Normale Superiore in the years
1860–1929. Sansone related that Vito Volterra, perhaps in 1922, had occasion to meet Lebesgue in Paris. Lebesgue asked Volterra for news about Vitali and when he heard that Vitali was teaching mathematics in secondary school in Genoa, surprised, he said: “I am pleased that Italy has the possibility to maintain mathematicians like Vitali in secondary schools”

I don't know whether the anecdote by Sansone is true or not; it may have been invented to make a point about meritocracy in Italy ("Vitali was a mathematician as good as, if not better than, Lebesgue, but the French made their own a national hero, while we sent ours to a classical high school"), or it could be true.
If it were true, Lebesgue's mockery would be out of place, if he had also been a high school teacher, as the OP suggests. However, Lebesgue taught at a high school while he was studying at university. Therefore, it would be unfair to say that the Lebesgue measure is the work of a high school teacher, even though that would be technically correct; it would be more accurate to say that the Lebesgue measure is the work of a university student.
On the other hand, the Vitali set is indeed the work of a high school teacher. In 1905, Vitali had already left university, though he had not yet abandoned scientific research (publishing with the Gamberini and Parmeggiani printing house is not exactly an indication of great academic popularity).

A somewhat famous case is Weierstrass who taught at the Lyceum Hosianum in Braunsberg for many years before obtaining a position at a university.
